My animation doesnt load while collaborating
local module = {}
local RPunchAnim = Instance.new("Animation")
local LPunchAnim = Instance.new("Animation")
local KickAnim = Instance.new("Animation")
local UppercutAnim = Instance.new("Animation")
        
RPunchAnim.AnimationId = "18426281478"
LPunchAnim.AnimationId = "18434268855"
KickAnim.AnimationId = "18434272823"
UppercutAnim.AnimationId = "18434276521"

    local debounce = false
    local isHit = false
    local hitCount = 0
    local timer = tick()
    local AnimPlay
    
    module.activateM1 = function(player)
        local Humanoid = player.Character.Humanoid
        local HRP = player.Character.HumanoidRootPart
        
        if not debounce then
            debounce = true
            
            if tick() - timer > 2 then
                hitCount = 0
            end
            
            timer = tick()
            
            hitCount += 1
            
            if hitCount == 1 then
                AnimPlay = Humanoid:LoadAnimation(RPunchAnim)
            elseif hitCount == 2 then
                AnimPlay = Humanoid:LoadAnimation(LPunchAnim)
            elseif hitCount == 3 then
                AnimPlay = Humanoid:LoadAnimation(RPunchAnim)
            elseif hitCount == 4 then
                AnimPlay = Humanoid:LoadAnimation(KickAnim)
                end
            end
            
            AnimPlay:Play()
            
            print(hitCount)
            
            wait(0.5)
            
            debounce = false
            
        
    end
return module



-Get rid of the error:
Note: My friends and I collaborated together, and we are not in the same Roblox group. I didn't animate the animation, and the animationIDs IDs are  correct (the animator, whp is the owner of the game, typed them himself twice).

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

The error you are getting is related to how you are specifying the AnimationId wrong.
Animation.AnimationId expects the Content datatype and not number, so you must use the proper format.

Assets and other content are reflected through formatted strings, each of which points to an online file or a file saved to the client's device. The basic structure is a protocol followed by :// and a string that varies according to the protocol.
[Protocol]://[String]

Below is a list of content IDs that would work:

"https://www.roblox.com/catalog/507771019" -- Web URL (will not work)
"http://www.roblox.com/asset/?id=507771019" -- Content ID (will work)
"rbxassetid://507771019" -- Content ID (alternative version, will work)


Here is the fixed script, using the rbxassetid:// prefix:
RPunchAnim.AnimationId = "rbxassetid://18426281478"
LPunchAnim.AnimationId = "rbxassetid://18434268855"
KickAnim.AnimationId = "rbxassetid://18434272823"
UppercutAnim.AnimationId = "rbxassetid://18434276521"

Note that prefixing http://www.roblox.com/asset/?id= to your ID would also work.

Animations and most other Roblox content is referenced by "rbxassetid://" followed by the ID numbers. You're only putting in the ID numbers.
It should look like this instead "rbxassetid://18426281478"
